# SAML Authentication in Objective-C iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, saml, idp

Trying to implement single sign on on my app using SAML.

I have a WKWebView that i redirect to the idp so that the user can login and then the idp sends a post request to my server with the authentication info where I generate a jwt token for the user of my app.

using decidePolicyForNavigationResponse I can tell when the webview received the final response but I can't access the response body.

I'm generally confused about how to implement SAML to my app.

How can I access response body and is there a better way of approaching this problem?